# select elements iterate by jquery, the first one remains unchanged

Tags: jquery

part of view is something like this

```
  <div id="edit_selected_attributes">
 <div>
  <select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_9">
 <option> Select  Com Weight</option>
 <option value="12">1</option>
 <option value="13">2</option>
 <option value="14">3</option></select>
</div>
<div>
 <select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_11">
 <option> Select  Composition</option>
 <option value="15">1</option>
 <option value="16">2</option>
 <option value="17">3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_12">
<option> Select  Composition</option>
<option value="18">1</option>
<option value="19">2</option>
<option value="20">3</option>
 </select></div>
<div>
<select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_16">
<option> Select  Composition</option>
<option value="22">1</option>
<option value="23">2</option>
<option value="24">3</option>
</select></div>
<div>
<select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_17">
<option> Select  Composition</option>
<option value="26">1</option>
<option value="27">2</option>
<option value="28">3</option>
```

Then I retrieved two numbers from database as a string like "12,16,18,22,28" Split them into array [12,16,18,22,28]

retrieve and iterate like this

```
  $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
    url:"{{url('library/inv_item/get_item_data')}}",
    async:false,
   data:{inv_item_id:inv_item_id},
   success: function(data4){  /* data4 = "12,16,18,22" */                                         
   var data5 = data4.split(',');

   $('.edit-select-attribute').each(function(ind,val){                    
    $.each(data5,function(i5,v5){
     var v5 = parseInt(v5);
       $('.edit-select-attribute').find('option[value='+v5+']').prop({'selected':true},);
   });
   });
  $('#editInvItemDiv').dialog('open');   
   },
  error: function(data5){},                            
   });
```

Showing the element in a ui dialog window.
The problem is that only last 4 select elements is iterated, the first select box is untouched.

[image: SelectElements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, assuming the index of the values in the returned string match the index of the `select` in the HTML, would be to `split()` the returned string in to an array and then provide a function to `val()` which returns the relevant value from the array based on the index of the current `select`. Try this:

```js
// in your AJAX success handler...
var data4 = "12,16,18,22,28";
var responseArr = data4.split(',');
$('select.form-control').val(function(i) {
  return responseArr[i];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit_selected_attributes">
  <div>
    <select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_9">
      <option> Select Com Weight</option>
      <option value="12">1</option>
      <option value="13">2</option>
      <option value="14">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_11">
      <option> Select Composition</option>
      <option value="15">1</option>
      <option value="16">2</option>
      <option value="17">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_12">
      <option> Select Composition</option>
      <option value="18">1</option>
      <option value="19">2</option>
      <option value="20">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_16">
      <option> Select Composition</option>
      <option value="22">1</option>
      <option value="23">2</option>
      <option value="24">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="form-control edit-select-attribute" id="edit_inv_attribute_id_17">
      <option> Select Composition</option>
      <option value="26">1</option>
      <option value="27">2</option>
      <option value="28">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that you should remove `async: false`. It's very bad practice and you don't need it anyway

Comment: There are three ajax calls at the same time, the third is dependent on the second, second is depended on the first. although calls are made from success handler, syncronous req makes the elements messy.

Comment: `syncronous req makes the elements messy` It shouldn't when done correctly. And even then, messy code is better than synchronous code which freezes the browser window.